# How to measure time taken (computation) for each task in Ganache/Truffle?

Tags: ganache, performance

If we have deployed a Dapp and using Ganache, how to measure the time taken for each step/task? or the total time taken for the entire application or the time taken for the creation of each block in Ganache.